# Add new Data to top of realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am using realtime database.

I know when i add new item to firebase it appear in the last position..
For example..  If i have list in my database called "lectures" and like that

```
Lectures: 
    lecture1:
        name:"lec 1 name"

    lecture2:
        name:"lec 2 name"

    lecture3:
        name:"lec 3 name"

    lecture4:
        name:"lec 4 name"
```

When i send new item (*ex.Lecture5*) to this list it will be added to bottom of it
Like that

```
Lectures: 
    lecture1:
        name:"lec 1 name"

    lecture2:
        name:"lec 2 name"

    lecture3:
        name:"lec 3 name"

    lecture4:
        name:"lec 4 name"

    lecture5:
        name:"lec 5 name"
```

Is there any way to make new item to be added to the top of list, like that:

```
Lectures: 
    lecture5:
        name:"lec 5 name"

    lecture1:
        name:"lec 1 name"

    lecture2:
        name:"lec 2 name"

    lecture3:
        name:"lec 3 name"

    lecture4:
        name:"lec 4 name"
```

And when add another new item appear like that:

```
Lectures: 
    lecture6:
        name:"lec 6 name"

    lecture5:
        name:"lec 5 name"

    lecture1:
        name:"lec 1 name"

    lecture2:
        name:"lec 2 name"

    lecture3:
        name:"lec 3 name"

    lecture4:
        name:"lec 4 name"
```

And so on...

If there is any way, please tell me

Answer (score 0):

I am using a firebase realtime database as well, and maybe there is a way that you can do it, but I fail to see the purpose of it, nor have I ever needed it.

Database is there to store the data, it makes absolutely no difference there in what order the values are stored, as you can and should get it ordered by given conditions when using the data on the client side.

Here is more info about sorting / ordering the values in realtime database
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sort_data

Comment: I also know to to use "order" methods...But what i want ti arrange data in realtime database,  not to arrange them in retrieving.. Do you understand what i want??

Comment: Yes I do, and do you understand, that this is pointless and also not possible due to the way firebase is storing data? Trying to do so is wrong by a principle, and it means that there is bad design somewhere in your app, if you think that you are are forced to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The child nodes are just sorted [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order) in ascending order in the console. It makes no difference while you are querying unless you are using `orderByKey()` method.

Comment: Yes,  i use orderByKey() method... And i found it hard to arrange items correctly in Recyclerview.. So need to arrange them in database instead

Comment: @MohamedA.Yousef are you trying to sort by keys? Then there's no way tbh. Either use Firestore which allows you to paginate data easily so you can fetch data in batches unlike rtdb where you are limited to `limitToLast` or `limitToFirst` methods.